# Use Python's hashlib to find the hash of something that isn't a complete byte

Tags: python

Is there a way to send a raw bitstring like '001' and hash that using Python's hashlib? Using the literal string '001' hashes the binary representation of the string which is 24 bits in length.

Comment: ask yourself: is there a way to read/write only 3 bits from/to memory, from/to file, from/to network? If you can answer that then you could use the emerged representation for hashing (or choose another if you'd like) e.g., hash eight 3 bits at a time (3 bytes at once) and pad with zeros if there are less (and pass number of bits). See also [Bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), [`bitstring` module](https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would have to define the meaning of the hash of three bits. The hashes in hashlib (and standard hashes in general) are defined with an input which is a sequence of bytes, so if you have less than one byte there's no standard definition.

For example, you might define that the hash of `'001'` should be equal to the hash of a single byte equal to `1` -- that is to say fill the other 5 bits with `0`. I'm not saying that's a "correct" definition, just that it makes sense. There must be some reason why you *don't* want the hash of the 3 bytes `'001'`, that you've chosen not to share. That reason might tell you the "correct" definition.

If you do make that definition, you can get the byte to hash using `chr(int('001', 2))` in Python2 or `int('001',2).to_bytes("big", 1)` in Python3. There might be a better way in 3.

Comment: I see, so hashes in hashlib have to be a number of bytes. Then I don't have a reason to hash an arbitrary number of bits.